# 'Flickity' Carousel Firefox Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a new eCommerce website and wish to use 'Flickity' carousel with custom jQuery & CSS code to give it a progress bar. It works great in Chrome, Opera, Edge etc., but not in Firefox as the carousel is missing although the progress bar still shows. However, resizing the window will then make it appear.

you can see the site here: http://bp177.betapark.co.uk/

I've tried min-height etc., as well as jQuery window load, but I just can't get anything to work.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated as I've spent hours so far trying to fix this.

```
.carousel-cell {
width: 100%;
}

html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}

<div class="main-carousel" data-flickity=''>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="/user/templates/flat-blue/slideshow-1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="/user/templates/flat-blue/slideshow-2.jpg"></div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-progress">
    <div class="progress"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var duration = 3;
var interval = 5;
var slider = document.querySelector(".main-carousel");
var sliderWrapper = document.querySelector(".main-carousel");
var progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress");

var flkty = new Flickity(slider, {
    cellSelector: ".carousel-cell",
    cellAlign: "center",
    contain: true,
    draggable: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    prevNextButtons: true,
    fullscreen: true,
    groupCells: true
});


// Main Progress Bar Function

var percentTime, step, tick;

function startProgressbar() {
    resetProgressbar();
    percentTime = 0;
    isPaused = false;
    tick = window.setInterval(increase, interval);
}

function increase() {
    if (!isPaused) {
        step = duration * 1000 / interval;
        percentTime += 100 / step;
        progressBar.style.width = percentTime + "%";
        if (percentTime >= 100) {
            flkty.next();
            startProgressbar();
        }
    }
}

function resetProgressbar() {
    progressBar.style.width = 0 + "%";
    clearTimeout(tick);
}

startProgressbar();

// Pause Control

var isPaused = false;

sliderWrapper.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    isPaused = true;
});

sliderWrapper.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    isPaused = false;
});

// Pause Progress Bar when it's Hovered Over

$(".carousel-progress").mouseenter(function() {
    isPaused = true;
});

$(".carousel-progress").mouseleave(function() {
    isPaused = false;
});

// Resets Progress Bar on Drag

flkty.on("dragMove", function(progress) {
    startProgressbar();
    isPaused = true; //(Disable/delete line if pause on hover is not in use)
});

// Resets Progress Bar on Click of Previous/Next Buttons and Page Dots

$(".previous, .next, .flickity-page-dots").click(function() {
    startProgressbar();
    isPaused = true; //(Disable/delete line if pause on hover is not in use)
});

// Controls Visibility of Previous/Next Buttons on Carousel Hover

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".flickity-viewport, .flickity-prev-next-button, .flickity-page-dots, .carousel-progress").mouseover(function() {
        $(".flickity-prev-next-button").css({
            "visibility": "visible",
            "opacity": "1"
        });
    });

    $(".flickity-viewport, .flickity-prev-next-button, .flickity-page-dots, .carousel-progress").mouseout(function() {
        $(".flickity-prev-next-button").css({
            "visibility": "hidden",
            "opacity": "0"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: my Firefox shows the progress bar, did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes the progress bar always shows, but not always the main carousel. On the occasions the carousel doesn't show, resizing the Firefox browser window will then get it show. The only solution I've found so far is to give the .carousel-cell a height in pixels, but this isn't ideal of course as I want it to be responsive.

Comment: see it: https://codepen.io/nevnein/pen/NBWdwb

Comment: Thanks I've seen this, but it has a fixed height which isn't practical in this scenario.

Comment: ok the problem is, that your .flickity-viewport has a height of 0px. That's the problem of wrong calculation your height of the images. Wrap a $(document).ready(function(){ ** your code **});  this line of codes waits until your document is fully loaded

Comment: Thank-you so much that works!!:) Can't believe I missed that!!:/ Thanks Again Michi